# Visual Studio freezes after loading Crystal Report

Tags: visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports

Asking this to see if anyone has a similar issue that they have resolved.

I running Visual Studio Community 2013 Update 5. I have installed Crystal Reports for Visual studio. It is 
CR for VS 13 SP 13.

```
CRforVS13SP25_0-10010309
```

As soon as I open a crystal report and start doing anything on it, the whole VS freezes. I am unable to open other aspx pages.

Freeze image:

[image]

Any way to resolve this?

Comment: Any error/exeption message or does it not even get that far? Do you just close it via task manager or does it respond after a period of time?

Comment: I close it via task manager. Anyway I solved it by installing CR for VS 13_18.